# Mobile App: MySQL Connection

Tags: android, mysql, ios, connection

I want to develop a native App for Android and iOS. The App communicates with a MySQL DB on an online server.

What's the best way to do this? Store the DB in the App or communicate with a live DB on a server right within the App? Is it secure to connect right from the App to the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need an app to communicate with a database, I use a server-side script (written in PHP).

Sample flow:

1. App performs an HTTP POST and includes all required variables in the
   header.
2. The script on the server queries the database.
3. The script returns the data as a JSON/XML array.

This sort of a configuration has several benefits, the most important one being that you do not have to distribute your database passwords - even if you encrypt them, it is a risk. You can also monitor/record/refuse connections with ease.

Finally, this implementation is platform-independent and will work on both Android and iOS.

This technique has worked successfully for me however, YMMV.

Comment: thank you very much. i think i will do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you would be able to store the database within the app was if it was a flatfile database.

You should not have any problems connecting to a MySql database on a server and if you want extra security encrypt your password and unencrypt it when you need to use it.

Comment: so it's secure even someone get's the app file? the connection data would be hardcoded in the app so thats what i'm worried about.

Comment: If the password is encrypted and someone gets the app file as long as they don't know how you unencrypt the password it will be secure. So even if they get the username and db ip they can't get in,.

Comment: thank you very much for the useful informations.